# angularjs - directive scope not cleaned up after binding to parent controller variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have been building a directive to allow the user to choose from a list of suggestions (laid out horizontally (similar to an autocomplete widget).

The directive (called 'suggestions') get its data source by binding to a controller model

I would like to user to be able to choose from the list of suggestions either by pressing the "enter" key or by clicking the mouse button.

Upon choosing an item from the suggestion box, the entire box is supposed to disappear (i.e. the model backing the suggestions is suppose to become an empty array)

The mouse click works marvelously - however the enter key press causes new items in scope.items to remain

You can replicate what I am talking about by loading up the example below then:

1 - click the "add" button - this will add an item "yea" into the directive scope's items array and update the DOM

2 - click on any options with the mouse - ng-click works marvelously and the suggestions disappear

3 - refresh the page and repeat step 1 - then use the left,right arrow key and press enter. Everything except 'yea' goes away

```
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">
<button ng-click="add()">add</button>
<h2>select:</h2>
<suggestions items="items" on-select="alert(selection)"></suggestions>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {name: 'foo', code: 1},
        {name: 'bar', code: 2},
        {name: 'tar', code: 3}
    ];
    $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.items.push({name: 'yea', code: 4});
    };
    $scope.alert = function (selection) {
        console.log(selection);
        $scope.items = [];
    }
});

app.directive('suggestions', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            items: "=",
            onSelect: "&onSelect"
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var currentIdx = -1;
            scope.highlightItem = function (item) {
                element.find('.suggestion-container>span.suggestion-item').removeClass('suggestion-item-selected');
                $(item).addClass("suggestion-item-selected");
                currentIdx = $(item).index();
            };
            // handle left, right arrow navigation
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                var spanSize = element.find('span.suggestion-item').size();
                if (scope.items.length == 0 || currentIdx == -1)
                    return;
                switch (e.which) {
                    case 37: // left
                        currentIdx = Math.max(currentIdx - 1, 0);
                        break;
                    case 39: // right
                        currentIdx = Math.min(currentIdx + 1, spanSize - 1);
                        break;
                    default:
                        return;
                }
                scope.highlightItem(element.find(".suggestion-container>span.suggestion-item:eq(" + currentIdx + ")"));
            });
            // handle enter key
            $(document).keydown(function (e) {
                if (scope.items.length <= 0 || currentIdx == -1)
                    return;
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        scope.onSelect({selection: scope.items[currentIdx]});
                        currentIdx = -1;
                    });
                }
            });
            // handle hover
            element.children('.suggestion-container').on('mouseenter', 'span.suggestion-item', function () {
                scope.highlightItem(this);
            });
            element.children('.suggestion-container').on('mouseleave', function () {
                element.find('.suggestion-container>span.suggestion-item').removeClass('suggestion-item-selected');
            });
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{items}}</div><div class="suggestion-container"><span ng-click="onSelect({selection:item})" class="suggestion-item" ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.name}}</span></div>'
    };
});
```

Style

```
     .suggestion-item-selected {
        background-color: #46b8da;
        cursor: pointer;
        color: #ffffff;
    }

    .suggestion-item {
        cursor: pointer;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;

        border-width: thin;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: #777777;

        margin-right: 2px;}
```

Thanks,

Comment: A console.out immediately after or inside the "e.which == 13" block reveals that the directive scope's items has indeed been reset to the empty array '[]', i.e. the binding worked. But subsequent calls to access the directive's scope.items shows that 'yea' was added back in. Almost seems like the Ctrl's add() method was inadvertently called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered my own question:

The reason is because "add()" is being called again. Pressing "left" "right" also had the side effect of focusing the "add" button